# Some time silent recording with Audio Record

Tags: android, audio-recording

I am using  Audio Record to record voice using android phone. It is working most of the time but some time on my moto g phone it records silent data. When I replay it I do not hear any thing. When I checked the
audio file it was there in the storage I played using media play from pc it was playing with out any voice .

`my code:`

```
int mSampleRate = 8000;
int mBufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(mSampleRate,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
byte bData[] = new byte[mBufferSize];
ByteArrayOutputStream encodedStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream( );
while (mIsRecording) {
    mRecorder.read(bData, 0, mBufferSize);
    encode(bData,encodedStream);
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Have you tested your code in another phone?

Comment: Yes I have tested my code with samsung phone too but it did not come

Comment: this code is not complete: E.g. where is the line(s) with `mRecorder=new AudioRecord(...,mSampleRate,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,mBufferSize);`?

Comment: Its there I have not posted it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys . Its was my mistake. I was using the audio recorder through JNI too and I was not releasing the audio record that's why whenever I tried to use audio record from java (Android SDK) it was not capturing any voice . Hope this will help to some one else .